# Installing OpenCV 3.2 with python 3.6 in windows10

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am new in computer vision.

I am trying to install the `opencv library 3.2` with `python 3.6` but I followed every tutorial.

However; I don't know what I've done wrong. I have installed `python 3.6 amd 64` and added it to the `PATH` ... then I have downloaded the `wheel of opencv 3.2` for `python 3.6 amd 64` then try to install it using `pip`.

However, it says that isn't supported in this platform. So, I  don't know what to do now. I'm trying to avoid the `CMake` ... stuff because I find it tough!!!

[The error mentioned in the prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFTO3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip checks whether name of a wheel contains platform specific words Eg.

> ad3‑2.0.2‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl

(python 2.7, windows 32-bit/x86) if I install it on python 3.6 it say it isn't supported on this platform but if I change wheel's name it trys to install it. Chceck which pip are you really using. You can't use x64 wheels on x86 interpreter. Some unofficial wheels for windows platform you can find here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Yeah it worked, Thank u very much for ur help,  but now I'm facing another prob which is : it has been installed but it says in the import error the DLL load failes and the module specified it wasn't found.

Comment: @Saitama I suggest to ask a new question, so more people will see new problem.